# A large scale TCP IP based pubsub systems

Tags: publish-subscribe, zeromq, tcp

I am designing a TCP/IP based pub/sub system. This is expected to have a high message update rate and also a large number of subscribers. 
I was looking at CometD before but we realised that the Bayeux protocols it supports is just JSON on Http. We don't want a Http overhead in this system. 
Now i am looking at ZeroMQ for a possible solution. Are there any other such systems out there which have been proven to handle large scale pub/sub over TCPIP?

Update - My publishers are just TCP/IP clients but my subscribers are web browser based widgets. As I understand, ZeroMQ does not have Http support for browser based subscribers. Are there any workarounds for such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be making contradictory requirements:

- You don't want HTTP overhead
- Your clients are browser-based widgets

If you can rewrite your clients you might consider a 0MQ to websocket bridge. There are a few floating around, like https://gist.github.com/1051872.

Also, when you explain your requirements, please provide figures. "High message update rate" and "large number of subscribers" means very little. 10/sec? 1M/sec? 50 subscribers? 50,000? Also, it's worth noting the average message size, whether you have to work over public Internet, and any other constraints.

Comment: Well, for a high-speed pub/sub system with low latency, Http would not be considered favourable because we just need a text based protocol system with low overheads. The consumers would be browsers though. So as you pointed out I will need a web-socket or something like that on the subscribers end.